# Line integral of $v_1$ along $\gamma$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

Given $\gamma : [0,2\pi] \to \mathbb{R}^3, t\mapsto (\cos(t), \sin(t), t)$ and $v_1\in C^1(\mathbb{R}^3, \mathbb{R}^3)$ with $v_1(x_1,x_2,x_3)=\begin{pmatrix} x_1x_2\\-x_1^2\\x_3 \end{pmatrix}$, find the line integral of $v_1$ along $\gamma$.

Here's my computation:$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}v_1(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)\, dt=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\begin{pmatrix} \cos(t)\sin(t)\\-\cos^2(t)\\t \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} -\sin(t)\\\cos(t)\\1 \end{pmatrix} \, dt=-\int_{0}^{2\pi}(\cos(t)\sin^2(t)+\cos^2(t)-t)\, dt \\ =-\frac{1}{12}(-6t(t-1)+4\sin^2(t)+3\sin(2t))\Bigg |_0^{2\pi}=\pi (2\pi-1)$$ is it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

You have to replace $$\cos^2(t)-t$$
by

$$\cos^3(t)-t$$
and
use the fact that

$$\cos(3t)=4\cos^3(t)-3\cos(t)$$
to compute
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\cos^3(t)dt.$$